# How to view exported mail file with Gnus properly?

Tags: gnus

Gnus has the feature to export the mail to file with "O m" (gnus-summary-save-article-mail) command.  I've been often using this feature to save the mail to the file for future reference.

However, I could not find the proper way to open the saved mail file with Gnus, so that we can properly extract the attached files, display with proper faces (colors), etc.

I appreciate if anyone knows and let me know how to do it.

regards,

Answer (score 4):

In order to visit a file containing emails, you need to create a
group from that file, which you can do with `gnus-group-make-doc-group`, bound to
<kbd>G f</kbd>  by default.

See [(gnus) Foreign Groups](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Foreign-Groups.html#Foreign-Groups)
for the gory details.