# How to open .eml files with mu4e?

Tags: mu4e, gnus, email

I would like to be able to open [`.eml`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Filename_extensions) files with mu4e and read them like regular mails. I've seen a [solution for Gnus](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44836/how-to-view-exported-mail-file-with-gnus-properly), but I would like to stay with mu4e. Any ideas?

Comment: What about this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400783/how-can-i-import-eml-files-in-mu4e-on-emacs

Comment: This solution partly answers my question. However, I would prefer to open eml files without having to index them with mu first. I would like to leave them where they are and not include them in my emails. Just like it is possible in Gnus and Thunderbird.

Comment: Another relevant [thread](https://github.com/djcb/mu/issues/1346). It seems that there's only two options (indexing and using mu view <path>. I suspect that the messages do not have to be put in a cur directory though (can be indexed wherever they are).